# Create table with date column that has only specific columns

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have to create this table :

```
Temps_ED (DateFacture, month, year)
```

where :

```
DateFacture :day+month+year
month: (month+year)
year : year
```

Comment: What **datatype** should these columns be?? And what **RDBMS** are you using?

Comment: date i assume? it's not specified but i think date, it'd be easy to just make'em varchar. and i'm using Oracle 21C

Comment: *it'd be easy to just make'em varchar* and that would result in you asking further questions in the future about how to deal with problems caused by dates stored as strings.

Comment: i think i can manage that, or at least find solutions for it,
for this i searched and didn't find smth helpful, or maybe the solution m imagining doesn't exist in the first place

Comment: Not entirely clear exactly what you are asking, but do not store the same value in multiple columns. Store the date *as a date* and if you need a column for month and year, create *computed* columns.

Comment: it's not really up to me soo.. but i think i'll do something like that, thanks !

Comment: what i'm asking for is if there's a way to make a column type date but only in a specific format as in "month date 'mm/dd'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle has two data types for storing date-time values.

- `DATE`
- `TIMESTAMP`

The both **always** have the components year, month, day, hour, minute, second. `TIMESTAMP` can, optionally, have fractional seconds and/or a timestamp. Therefore, you **must** have a time component if you are using a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data type.

> what i'm asking for is if there's a way to make a column type date but only in a specific format as in "month date 'mm/dd'"

No, both `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` are binary data types; they do not store any format. If you want a format then you need to convert it from binary data to formatted data (i.e. a string) but this does not mean that you should store your values as strings; you should store them as the binary data and then format it when you retrieve/display it.

---

One solution is to store a `DATE` and then use virtual columns to get the other formats; this will ensure that all the columns are consistent.

```sql
CREATE TABLE temps_ed (
  value        DATE,
  datefracture VARCHAR2(10)
               GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_CHAR(value, 'YYYY-MM-DD')),
  month        VARCHAR2(7)
               GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_CHAR(value, 'YYYY-MM')),
  year         NUMBER(4,0)
               GENERATED ALWAYS AS (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM value))
);

INSERT INTO temps_ed (value) VALUES (SYSDATE);
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM temps_ed;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | DATEFRACTURE | MONTH | YEAR |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2021-12-04T14:41:37 | 2021-12-04 | 2021-12 | 2021 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b5d20c0c62cc8300aba57efc32ca2c65)*

Comment: woah this will work!! thanks so much sir !

Comment: _"woah this will work!! thanks so much sir ! "_   There's a bigger lesson here.  Never get fixated on some pre-conceived solution.  And the less you know about a given technology, the more important is that lesson.

Comment: ummm sure ig? thanks for the wisdom?